# Show that $f$ is not $\mathcal{T}-\mathcal{T}'$ continuous.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the standard topology on $\Bbb R$ and $\mathcal{T}'$ be the upper limit topology on $\Bbb R$. Consider $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x,x\le1 \\ x+1, x >1 \end{cases}$$ show that $f$ is not $\mathcal{T}-\mathcal{T}'$ continuous.

What is meant by this $\mathcal{T}-\mathcal{T}'$ continuity? Are they asking me to show that if I take a set in the codomain that would be open in the domain, then $f$ is not $\mathcal{T}-\mathcal{T}'$ if the preimage isn't open?

So if $O$ is a set in the codomain in the sense that it would be open in the domain then I'm to look at $f^{-1}[O]$ to determine continuity?

Comment: I have no guess as to what $\mathcal T-\mathcal T$ might mean.  Are you sure there isn't a typo?  Given that they define $\mathcal T'$, perhaps that's meant to figure in the question somewhere?

Comment: Sorry. It should be $\mathcal{T}-\mathcal{T}'$

Comment: So, maybe it means discontinuous as a map from $\mathbb R, \mathcal T$ to $\mathbb R, \mathcal T'$  or maybe the other way round?  But why guess?  Surely your reference has used this notation before.

Comment: I don't know if this books is freely available, but it seems to be at some uni's website so I guess it is. Check page 108 (continuous functions) solved problems no 3 (https://qcpages.qc.cuny.edu/~jdodziuk/320-s2019/Seymour%20Lipschutz%20-%20Schaum's%20Outline%20of%20General%20Topology-McGraw-Hill%20(1968).pdf)

Comment: So look at pages $1-107$ until you spot the first use of this notation.  I expect they'll define it there.  I really don't think it is standard.

Comment: Found it. Should I delete the question or keep it here in case someone else meets this notation and doesn't know what it is?

Comment: My view is that this notation is highly non-standard, so I doubt it will recur.  I suggest deleting the question.  Alternatively, you could post your own solution and explain the notation in the process.  I assume that my guess was correct?  It's really the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Oh, I see that someone has posted what looks like a complete answer (labeled as a hint).  If that answer works for you, you could just accept it and leave the post intact.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Suppose $f:(\Bbb{R}, \tau )\to( \Bbb{R}, {\tau}' )$ is continuous.

$(\Bbb{R}, \tau )$ is connected.

Continuous image of a connected set is connected.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it means that it is not continuous as a functions from $(\Bbb R,\mathcal T)$ into itself. And indeed it is not: $[2,\infty)$ is a closed set, but $f^{-1}\bigl([2,\infty)\bigr)$ is not.

Comment: I doubt it, as there would be no reason to mention $\mathcal T'$. Did you mean to say "from $(\Bbb R,\mathcal T)$ to   $(\Bbb R,\mathcal T')"$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet No, or at least not when I posted my answer. But the question was edited after that. The original version said “$\mathcal T-\mathcal T$ continuous”.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal T$-$\mathcal T'$ continuity is shorthand for

> continuous as a map between $(\Bbb R, \mathcal T)$ to $(\Bbb R, \mathcal T')$.

The function itself is purely $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ so to discuss continuity we need two topologies: one on the domain and one on the co-domain. Continuity is just *defined* as usual: the *inverse image* of an open set of the co-comain must be an open set in the domain, always.

In this case you could consider the open set in the codomain $O:=[1,2) \in \mathcal T'$. What is $f^{-1}[O]$? Is it open in $\mathcal T$?